# Asp.Net MVC validation annotation regular expression attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

When I have a checkbox in my form it is not enough to mark the matching property as Required because a true or false is sent as it's value.

Whats the best way to validate this in the model? I was thinking a regular expression to match the string true but I am either not writing it correctly or it does not work on a Boolean property.

```
public bool FeeAgree
    {
        get
        {
            return _feeAgree;
        }
        set
        {
            _feeAgree = value;
        }
    }
```

Above is the property I am trying to validate. Using the Required attribute does not work because the Html.CheckBoxFor creates a hidden field so there is always a valueof either true or false passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any data annotation for boolean properties. If the value is not `true` or `false` the default model binder will handle the case when trying to parse it and add a model error. So basically just by the fact of having such model property it would only accept `true` or `false`. Every other value would be considered as error.

If you were using a nullable boolean you could enforce it to have a value with the `Required` attribute:

```
[Required]
public bool? FeeAgree { get; set; }
```

---

To ensure that the user checked the checkbox you could write a custom validation attribute:

```
public class MustBeTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return value != null && (bool)value;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
[MustBeTrue(ErrorMessage = "You must accept the terms and conditions")]
public bool FeeAgree { get; set; }
```

Comment: That's the problem, it always has a value... if the value is false (meaning they did not check the box) then I want to send an error back.

Comment: @JBeckton, OK, now I understand. Please see my update about the custom attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This solution could be extended to include client side validation.

```
public class MustBeTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable {

    public override bool IsValid(object value) {
        return value is bool && (bool)value;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(
        ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context) {

        return new ModelClientValidationRule[] {
        new ModelClientValidationRule {
            ValidationType = "checkboxtrue",
            ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage
        }};
    }
}
```

Then if the view included a bit of jquery code to add the "checkboxtrue" validation type...

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("checkboxtrue", function (options) {
    if (options.element.tagName.toUpperCase() == "INPUT" && options.element.type.toUpperCase() == "CHECKBOX") {
        options.rules["required"] = true;
        if (options.message) {
            options.messages["required"] = options.message;
        }
    }
});
```

The result is client-side checkbox validation